# Is there a limit to the number of nodes and links a D3.js force layout can have?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I was wondering if anyone knows examples of D3 force layouts with many nodes. I am working on a huge datasets and, depending on how I filter the data, it would result in graphs with:

- 2,000 nodes and 15,000 links
- 11,000 nodes and 16,000 links
- 12,000 nodes and 200,000 links
- 30,000 nodes and 671,000

Especially for the last two I am worried the page will take forever to load and that any interactivity (like dragging around or clicking on a node to highlight only other nodes that are directly connected to it) would result in an unusable interface.

Is there a set limit to the number of nodes and links the force layout can handle?

Comment: i dont know about the limit, but working with huge data probably will be painful for some users (it depends on machine they use), a good solution is to render the layout server side, you can find some good guides around the net.